# Content Editor and RSS Viewer Conflict

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-editor-web-part, rss

I'm using the RSS Viewer webpart on a page with no issue.  If I add a Content Editor Webpart to the the page (doesn't matter if I add content or leave it as the blank default) the RSS Viewer works until the page is Published.  Once published all it get is the Waiting graphic and the feed never renders.

Has anyone seen anything like this?  Any ideas what it is doing?

Comment: Hi Dan, you have this figured out? I am in the same boat. I have SharePoint 2013 + March 2013 CU.

Comment: Nope still haven't found a reason for it to happen or a way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

AFter adding an RSS Viewer web part onto your desired page, if you may notice the headlines& content only being visible when the page is checked out, add a script editor web part to the same page that you have the RSS Viewer.  In it, add the following code:

```
<Script Type="text/javascript"> 
function CustomUpdateFormDigest() 
{ 
  if(window._spPageContextInfo != null) 
  { 
    var $v_2 = window._spPageContextInfo; 
    var $v_3 = $v_2.webServerRelativeUrl; 
    var $v_4 = window._spFormDigestRefreshInterval; 

    UpdateFormDigest($v_3, $v_4); 
  } 
} 

CustomUpdateFormDigest(); 
</Script>
```

I found this solution here:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/98a4e93e-5073-4b39-b379-6cc3eed2d984/rss-viewer-web-part-not-working-after-installing-kb2767793?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

They also recommended adding it to the Master Page, or turning off security validation for the pages containing the RSS Viewer web part via Central Admin->Web Application->General Settings.

Comment: This worked for me.  I actually just added it into the existing content editor webpart I had there already.

Answer (score 0):

Dan, I had the same problem and was using the content editor to redict the page. I managed to get round this by using an HTML Form web part and put the HTML in there. I read something about a published page works as one form and this miight be causing the issue.

HTML WebForm worked for me

Comment: Graham you are the man! :) **The HTML WebForm solution worked for me too!** Some key facts in my scenario: - The page is an old 2007 master page running on 2010 environment. In "compatibility" mode. When RSS Viewer Web Part in v4.master it works fine (even with content editors)
- Everything was working on August 2012 CU. RSS Viewer Web Part stopped working when we upgraded to SharePoint 2010 SP2
- The RSS Viewer Web Part stops working when there are other content editor web parts on the page
- Use the "HTML WebForm" web part as Graham suggests, not a Content Editor as some other articles sugge